# How to make async requests from PHP to node.js with a response?

Tags: php, ajax, node.js

I currently have a system like this:

An ajax gets sent from a website to .php file, which then sends a request to my node.js server and waits for a response and returns it to the ajax. I use express to listen for requests:

```
app.get('/abc/', function (req, res) {
console.log(req);
});
```

Currently I use **file_get_contents** to send a request from PHP:

```
$r = file_get_contents("http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].":9991/abc/?secret=123&price=500&token=$token");
```

This works just fine, however, it's syncronised so multiple ajax requests to this php file get queued up, which I don't want. I want them all to execute at the same time, sending requests to my server and waiting for a response. Is that possible to do with PHP? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could use pthreads, it's a PHP extension which allow you to use threads, The requests would still queued up, but it would only take the thread to start before the next Queued item would execute, and it will not wait until the file_get_contents() function finishes

Comment: Please don't use pthreads for this, there's an answer that's correct, using pthreads in this instance is the worst thing imaginable.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#async-requests) lib or [curl_multi_exe](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php)

Guzzle is OOP-style library - more effictivily and your tests

Curl simple and quick way to achieve the desired behavior.